# Using MYSQL and dropdowns

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I almost got a dropdown pulling from my DB and posting to it as well to work. I got it to pull down the data and for it to submit to the DB. Still a stump. If I have example "ABC Trucking" as an option. It only posts "ABC" to table1. For whatever reason it doenst post two words? Any Ideas? See where the carriername dropdown is in the div.

My Code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"] == "Submit")
{
    for ($count = 1; $count <= 9; $count++)
    {
        $fields[$count] = "";
        if (isset($_POST["field" . $count . ""]))
        {
            $fields[$count] = trim($_POST["field" . $count . ""]);
            //echo $fields[$count] . "<br />";
        }
    }

    $con = mysql_connect("local", "user", "pass");
    mysql_select_db("DB", $con);

    $carriername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['carriername']);
    $fromzip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fromzip']);
    $tozip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tozip']);
    $typeofequipment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['typeofequipment']);
    $weight = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['weight']);
    $length = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['length']);
    $paymentamount = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['paymentamount']);
    $contactperson = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contactperson']);
    $loadtype = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['loadtype']);

    $insert = "INSERT INTO table1 (`carriername` ,`fromzip` ,`tozip` ,`typeofequipment` ,`weight` ,`length` ,`paymentamount` ,`contactperson` ,`loadtype`) VALUES('$carriername' ,'$fromzip' ,'$tozip' ,'$typeofequipment' ,'$weight' ,'$length' ,'$paymentamount' ,'$contactperson' ,'$loadtype');";
    mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());

    $select = "SELECT `carriername` ,`fromzip` ,`tozip` ,`typeofequipment` ,`weight` ,`length` ,`paymentamount` ,`contactperson` ,`loadtype` FROM `table1` ORDER BY `paymentamount` DESC;";
    $result = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
</script>
<style ="text-align: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></style>
</head>
<body>
<div
 style="border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 16px 20px 20px; width: 400px; background-color: rgb(236, 233, 216); text-align: center; float: left;">
<form action="" method="post";">
  <div
  style="margin: 8px auto auto; width: 300px; font-family: arial; text-align: left;"><br>
  <table style="font-weight: normal; width: 100%; font-size: 12px;"
 border="1" bordercolor="#929087" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
   <table
 style="font-weight: normal; width: 100%; text-align: right; font-size: 12px;"
 border="1" bordercolor="#929087" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 10%;">Carrier:</td><td>
 <?php  

$con = mysql_connect("local", "user", "pass");
    mysql_select_db("DB", $con);

$query=("SELECT * FROM table2"); 

$result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Unable to Make the Query:" . mysql_error() ); 
echo "<select name=carriername>";   

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){  

echo "<OPTION VALUE=".$row['carriername'].">".$row['carriername']."</OPTION>"; 
} 

echo "</select>";  


?>
              </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td style="width: 35%;">Pick Zip:</td><td> <input id="fromzip" name="fromzip" maxlength="50"
 style="width: 100%;" type="text">
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td style="width: 35%;">Drop Zip:</td><td> <input id="tozip" name="tozip" maxlength="50"
 style="width: 100%;" type="text">
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td style="width: 35%;">Load Type:</td><td> <input id="loadtype" name="loadtype" maxlength="50"
 style="width: 100%;" type="text">
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td style="width: 35%;">Rate:</td><td> <input id="paymentamount" name="paymentamount" maxlength="50"
 style="width: 100%;" type="text">
        </tr>
          </tbody>
  </table>
  <p style="text-align: center;"><input name="submit" value="Submit"
 class="submit" type="submit"></p>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
<p style="margin-bottom: -20px;">&nbsp;</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of :

```
echo "<OPTION VALUE=".$row['carriername'].">".$row['carriername']."</OPTION>";
```

use this

```
echo "<OPTION VALUE='".$row['carriername']."'>".$row['carriername']."</OPTION>";
```

notice *'* in ur value...concate *''* to your value attr.. so that it makes it a string....

EDITED

```
echo "<select name='carriername'>";   
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
  echo "<OPTION VALUE=".$row['carriername'].">".$row['carriername']."</OPTION>"; 
} 
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: With that it doesnt read all the carriers now. And it returned the only option showing "Bush Trucking" like this "Abc Trucking>Abc Trucking"

Comment: Aslo I copied yours the way you had it and it was expecting a ; on the line.

Comment: for whatever reason with your code it doesnt query all the options. Example I have ABC Trucking & Bush Trucking to select from in table2. I put you code in and it would only query Bush Trucking, and when I submitted it, it posted as "Abc Trucking>Abc Trucking" to table1

Comment: actually looking at the table it posted as: Abc Trucking>Abc Trucking</OPTION><OPTION VALUE=